How to get https response error code from AWS SDK request in golang?
I'm building a rest api for user authentication using AWS Cognito and I can't wrap my head around handling errors returned by the api call.
I'm trying to convert the APIError to a custom type for a JSON return style.
This is my custom error type:
type UsecaseError struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func (e *UsecaseError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(`{"code": %s, "message": %s}`, e.Code, e.Message)
}

The Code field should represent the https code of the error returned by the api.
And based on the AWS documentation this is how I tried to handle the APIError.
if err != nil {
        var apiErr smithy.APIError
        if errors.As(err, &apiErr) {
            return nil, &usecase.UsecaseError{
                Code:    apiErr.ErrorCode(),
                Message: apiErr.ErrorMessage(),
            }
        }
        slog.Error(err.Error())
        return nil, usecase.UnknownError(http.StatusBadRequest, "An unknown error occured")
}

But the problem is that the SDK does not provide any way of retrieving the https error code from the apiErr. Since apiErr.ErrorCode is a string that can't be converted to an int.
Should I use a switch statement to iterate over all apiErr.ErrorCode possibilities and return the int error code that fits?
This solution seems very tedious.
